# Decoding flight Arrival / Departure time format

Tags: decode, datetime-format

I've been using a real time flight traffic API lately and I'm stuck at formating the arrival / departure times from a json response.

They come like this:

```
{
"dep_schd":1426843500,
"arr_schd":1426849800,
"departure":1426844020,
"arrival":1426849221
}
```

It doesn't look like anything I've seen before. Any ideas on how to make these times readable?

As a bonus, I can give you how an estimated time arrival looks like:

```
"eta":1426849221
```

Thank you

***Edit:***

Okay guys, with a bit more research and the help from you guys I managed to convert my date to a human readable date like this:

```
var departure = $('#departure');
var departureDate = new Date(json.departure * 1000);
departure.html(departureDate.toUTCString());
```

Now what I get is something like this:

```
Fri, 20 Mar 2015 09:33:40 GMT
```

My question is how can I make it simpler? So as I can get something like this:

```
Fri, 20 Mar 2015 09:33
```

Comment: They're unix epoch times (ie, number of seconds from Jan 1st, 1970 at 00:00 GMT).

Answer (score 2):

This is [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). The number of seconds since 01 Jan 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

On Unix you can use functions like `localtime` or `gmtime` and `strftime` to convert it to a human-readable form. Most languages have similar functions for dealing with these unix timestamps.

---

To display it in another format, use the "get" functions on the Date object (since it looks like this is JavaScript). For example `departure.getUTCHours()`.

A better solution though is to use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) to format the date easily:

```
var mDeparture = new moment(departureDate);
departure.html(mDeparture.format('YYYY-mm-dd'));
```

Comment: Solved the initial problem, thank you. I updated my post with another question.

Answer (score -1):

The format which your are displaying is called Epoch and it is then converted into human readable format.Here is a online site where u can get this in readable format http://www.epochconverter.com/

But you didn't mention in which language you want to convert , every language as methods to convert this in human readable and then you have to pick which info you want from it.

Comment: They're called epoch times, not "timestamp".

Comment: I dnt know How you read my answer i attached a link and that clear in the answer. In every Enterprises application its key name is timestamp not epoch.